# Firefox randomly changes pixel size with no apparent reason

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

I'm testing a website on multiple browsers.

It works in chrome, Edge, Canary and even IE

However the button is off by about one pixel in Firefox

This is the Button, that is a little bit off, to the left:

[image: this is the Button, that is a little bit off, to the left]

When you press "Ctrl + Shift + I" on that part, to debug it, it says:

```
border-left-width > 1.6 px
```

If you then open the dropdown (to see where it's defined), it tells me, where from the CSS it gets it from:

```
.settings-accordion .panel-default > 2px
```

When I manually change this number, with inline styles, it always rounds down to the next smaller multiple of 0.8.

[this is the screenshot of how firefox interprets the css code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLzcz.png)

If you than manually put it to 2.4 - 3.1 px, it works in this browser, but all the other Browsers are off.

How is this possible?

Comment: http://cruft.io/posts/percentage-calculations-in-ie/

Comment: @mplungjan
Thank, you, but I do not use percentages in there. So, the browser shouldn't be rounding anything.